# The name 'MyApp' isn't a class. Try correcting the name to match an existing class. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I don't know what is the problem is / how to fix this while I tring to code it shows this error on the test folder widget_test.dart

[image]x

```
 testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
```

Comment: You need to keep the name of the root widget class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the pumpWidget method change "const MyApp()" to the same name of your first Widget class. The class you instance on the runApp function, inside the main function on the main.dart file.

For example, if your main.dart content is:

```
void main() async {
     runApp(MyGreatApp());
}
        
class MyGreatApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyGreatApp();
        
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
              //rest of code ...
       );
  }
}
```

Put in your widget_test.dart file:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(const MyGreatApp()); //<-
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```
 await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp());
```

at widget_test.dart file, if your main.dart begins like this:

```
void main() runApp(
MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the word "const"

Answer (score 1):

I think because you did not import a file main.dart into widget_test.dart
You should insert "import 'package: yourapp folder/main.dart;'" It should be working.

Answer (score 0):

try importing main.dart
`import 'package:appName/main.dart';`

if it's work, try the app.dart
`import 'package:appName/app.dart';`